# How to move circle with arrow keys?

Tags: java

I want to move a white circle on a black background using left and right arrow keys. The KeyListener is working (using System.out.print) but the circle does not move when keys are pressed. I think it has to do with the x & y positions (xPos, yPos).

```
private static final int SPEED = 50, BALL_SIZE = 50;
private int dx;
private int xPos, yPos;

public Background() {

    addKeyListener(this);

    setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    // the starting point of ball
    xPos = 100; 
    yPos = 700;

    dx = SPEED;
    }

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // screen size
    int width = getWidth();

    xPos += dx;

    // boundaries
    if (xPos < 100) {
        xPos = 100;
        dx = SPEED;
    }
    else if (xPos > width - BALL_SIZE) {
        xPos = width - BALL_SIZE;
        dx = -SPEED;
    }
    repaint();
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) { // right arrow key
        dx++;
    }
    else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) { // left arrow key
        dx--;
    }
    else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) { // space bar
        // shoot laser!
    }

    System.out.println("After");
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillOval(xPos, yPos, BALL_SIZE, BALL_SIZE);
}
```

Comment: Why is the `actionPerformed` method there. Why are you changing `dx` in your `keyPressed` event handler if you're not using `dx` for the actual drawing?

Comment: el classico -if i had a penny for each one of these

Comment: @RealSkeptic I thought actionPerformed would help with moving the circle to a new position. I did originally changed the dx to xPos but it did not work (though I will change it back thanks)